# Disable spinner when fragment is loading

Tags: android, android-fragments, spinner, disable

I am displaying a list in a fragment by selecting an option from spinner. Issue is spinner is selectable when the list is loading meanwhile progress bar is showing but spinner is clickable/touchable. Spinner is outside of framelayout in a different linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/spin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/dashbar_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_select"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearance"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/select_option"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    </TextView>

<com.my.Controller.SpinnerReselect
    android:overlapAnchor="false"
    android:id="@+id/date_spin"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_dropdown"
    android:theme="@style/roundSpin">
</com.my.Controller.SpinnerReselect>


</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/dash_spin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/multiFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE); in if else but it is enabling spinner before loading of list.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved disabled the spinner in activity where frame layout is loading and enabled it in fragment class when loading is finished